# Reusing old intents android

Tags: android, forms, android-intent, reusability

So I have on two of my forms a back and next button, on the first form when you press next it loads the second form, now if you press the back button on the second form it loads the first form, however now there are two intents for the same form. How do I prevent this from occurring?

first form start button:

```
  final Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), step_1_to_4.class);
            startActivity(i);



        }
        });
```

Second form back button is the following:

```
    final Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.step1_back_button);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HKA_manual_Calibration_v2_no_tabsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

so when the user goes back and forth between these two activities it results in multiple activities being created.

Comment: Chek out what you can do in androidmanifest.xml, "SingleTask" and "SingleInstance" etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the code above, there will be only *one* intent in your case and that is to start activity for second form. When you press *back* key, it actually resumes your previous activity, who's intent is already there (existing in that activity) and can be retrieved via `getIntent()`

Comment: The problem I am having is that when you use the android OS back button there will be multiple forms of the same activity. Also I am a bit confused by what getIntent() is used for in this case.

Comment: set `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` as your activity's attribute in manifest

Answer (score 0):

android:launchMode="singleInstance"

add the above line in your manifeast file for the activities.